# Postgresql multiple join, slow query after add where clause at the end of query

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query with 20 left join. One of the left join query is a subquery for searching countries where orders are made. When I put where clause at the end of my query it slows down 10 times, but the cost given by explain analyze remains the same. My question is what is best practice to write queries in PostgreSQL when we have multiple join and result of the join is making on impact of all result. Should I add where to another subquery to filter rows earlier? Or should i made this whole query as a subquery, then I put where condition in outer query?
Slowness of this query is only when parameter :val is set to null.

```
select a.name, b.name, c.name ...
from
a 
left join (subquery select ... where name = coalesce(:val,b.name)) b on a.1 = b._a_id 
left join (another subquery) c on a.1 = c.a_id
left join (another subquery) ...
where b.name = coalesce(:val,b.name)
```

Comment: Please show us the execution plan for each form of the query.  You do that by putting `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` before the query text.  Please edit your question to include the plans as formatted text, or since they will be very large, post them on https://explain.depesz.com/ and include the inks in your question

Comment: If your query has 20 left joins, you are almost certainly hitting the join_collapse_limit (and possibly from_collapse_limit and geqo_threshold).  Read up on these here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html.

Comment: Thanks for information about join_collapse_limit. When I change this setting to 30 it speed up my query x2. I manage to solve this performance issue by changing where condition to `where (:val is null or exists(select 1 from x where x.name = :val)`